# How to apply random image geometric transformation simultaneously to multiple images?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tensorflow and fully convolutional network to do regression on image.
I want to augment data by random flip/rotation, but how can I apply them simultaneously to input and output image tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, functions like `tf.random_flip_left_right` can be used only if there are no covariant variables. If there are, for example if your output is an image of labels, then you need to apply the same random operation to all of them.

I see two ways to do it:

1. You basically rewrite the random operations to work with several tensors. For example, to replace `tf.random_flip_left_right`, you could use

   ```
   coin = tf.less(tf.random_uniform((), 0., 1.), 0.5)
   im1 = tf.cond(coin, lambda: tf.flip_left_right(im1), lambda: im1)
   im2 = tf.cond(coin, lambda: tf.flip_left_right(im2), lambda: im2)
   ...
   ```
2. You stack all your tensors together before the random op:

   ```
   all_im = tf.stack([im1, im2,...], axis=2)
   all_im = tf.random_flip_left_right(all_im)
   [im1, im2, ...] = tf.split(all_im, [im1.shape[2], im2.shape[2], ...], axis=2)
   ```

   This second solution works only if all of the tensors have the same spatial range.

Comment: Performance- (in particular, memory-)wise, would you agree that solution 1 should perform much more efficiently?