# tf.image.random_flip_left_right() for multiple images together

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to randomly flip several input images of different sizes in my input pipeline.
The flip needs to be consistent for the different images - either all are flipped or none.
Since using [`tf.image.random_flip_left_right()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_flip_left_right) is inadequate for this, I did this instead:

```
images = [img1, img2]
def fliplr(*args):
    return [tf.image.flip_left_right(t) for t in args]
def id(*args):
    return args
img1, img2 = tf.cond(tf.random_uniform([1]) > 0.5, fliplr(images), id(images), name='fliplr')
```

This is part of a function called by `tf.Dataset.map()` with my input dataset object.

However I am getting this error from the `flip_left_right` line:

> ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 1. 
>   Shapes are [240,320,3] and [240,320,1].
>
> From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'flip_left_right/image' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [240,320,3], [240,320,1].

I think this is because my images are of different sizes (240x320, either 1 or 3 channels) but I don't understand why this would matter.

How can I resolve this error? Alternatively, is there a better way to get what I want that avoids this error?

I am using TensorFlow-1.8 (but can upgrade if required).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply random image geometric transformation simultaneously to multiple images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502264/how-to-apply-random-image-geometric-transformation-simultaneously-to-multiple-im)

Comment: I missed the fact that `tf.random_uniform()` is called with an empty shape to make it scalar. That way the solution there (also posted here by Albert) works for me. I will verify this and mark as duplicate.

Comment: Though note the second solution given there does not work here and gives a similar error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like this?

```
do_flip = tf.random_uniform([]) > 0.5
img1 = tf.cond(do_flip, lambda: tf.image.flip_left_right(img1), lambda: img1)
img2 = tf.cond(do_flip, lambda: tf.image.flip_left_right(img2), lambda: img2)
```